# is there anyway to call lambda function with html contents?

Tags: php

```
function sample($test1, $test2, $inner_html) {
    $html = call_user_func($inner_html);
    echo $test1 .  ' ' . $test2 . ' ' . $html;
}


sample('test1', 'test2', function(){
                    echo 'first test.'
      ?>
       <b>this is a test.</>
      <?
                    echo 'last test.';
});
```

Comment: The question whether outputting html inside the lambda like that is odd when looking at the context where the lambda is used. The example code doesn't make much sense. Your `sample` function will never execute the callback. Also, if you want to concatenate, as indicated in `sample`, why does the lambda not `return` but `echo`?

Comment: I modified the code and yes sir I know that, but is it possible to call function something like that?

Comment: I'd consider this a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put something out you can only get that output if you buffer the output using the [output control](http://php.net/book.outcontrol)’s [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start):

```
function sample($test1, $test2, $inner_html) {
    ob_start();
    $returnValue = call_user_func($inner_html);
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    echo $test1 .  ' ' . $test2 . ' ' . $output;
}
```